# Can Playwright be used to launch a browser instance

Tags: python, browser, playwright, playwright-python

I'm finding that in some cases web pages are being rendered in one browser materially different than another browser.  Specifically, Playwright running webkit is rendering a different structure than what I see when viewing the page in a standalone Chrome browser.  No clue why and I can't do anything about it.  This isn't a Playwright issue, it is rendering it the same way as a standalone browser would.  Problem is I don't know of an up-to-date webkit based browser for Windows.

Is there a way using just Playwright to open a browser window that will let me manually enter a url and inspect the page as Playwright renders it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Playwright's codegen tool and open the webkit browser

```
playwright codegen -b webkit
```

Comment: How do I do this for msedge?

Answer (score 0):

In playwright.config you have option

channnel: "chrome"

So with this you will start chrome, not chromium driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command to launch a webkit browser with a desktop safari user agent:

```
npx playwright codegen -b webkit --device "Desktop Safari"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests safari engine on windows

```
npx playwright open --browser webkit
```

> available options: `chromium`, `firefox`, `webkit` or `all`